# When viewing a dataframe, e.g., view(df), some columns say they are negative

Tags: rstudio

So after a recent Rstudio and R update when I view a df using view(df) and hover the mouse over a variable (column), the first 50 variables give their correct column index order but past that they show a negative number. For example, hovering over column 50, shows 50, while hovering over column 51 shows -40. What is going on here? Very weird.